# mysql query to search multiple values in comma separated list with AND clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have following table

```
Id     | Userdefined01
------------------------
1      | 1,2,4,5
2      | 2,5
3      | 4,6,8
4      | 1,5
```

I want to write a query to find all Ids having values 2 AND 5  in userdefined01 field. Is that possible?

Comment: It's a bad idea to store comma separated data in a column. You're breaking normalization. Don't do it unless you have a very good reason for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `FIND_IN_SET()` -- a builtin function for mysql to search a string inside a CSV.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET('2', Userdefined01) > 0 AND
        FIND_IN_SET('5', Userdefined01) > 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4023/1)
- [MySQL FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

If you have time to alter the schema, you need to denormalize it. Looking on the example, it may be `Many-to-Many` relationship so you can break it into 3-table design.

Comment: Thanks JW, that worked. I am trying to fetch some report from a product and that is designed this way. Can't change it.